# Autoupdate Google Sheet range

Tags: google-sheets

I have a logger that sends data to a Google Sheet every 5 minutes (by adding a new row to it).

I would like the charts I associated with the sheet to update their range automatically. If possible, I would like to avoid scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you should be able to set the chart range to the appropriate columns. Such as A:A. Can you share what the Data range for your chart is. Shown here:[image: Example]

In the above example, let's say columns I thru AG were going to go on in perpetuity due to logging. I could put I:AG in the data range field but it will auto update to the last row in the sheet. If you want to work around using this, add a bunch of blank rows at the bottom of the sheet and you will rarely need to update the range (&add more rows.)

Comment: Thank you. My range is like A1:B19000, updating every minute. I noticed that the pivot table accepts A:B, but not the charts (it immediately corrects to the last cell value).

Comment: I think, despite being corrected, the Chart still assumes the whole column, so your suggestion seems to work. Thanks!